# GWT Suggestbox define suggest oracle after instantiation

Tags: gwt, uibinder, suggestbox

I've defined a suggestbox in UIBinder, and I need to dynamically set its SuggestOracle.  All the examples I've seen show that you can only define the suggestoracle at instantiation, but I need to define this AFTER the fact.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Found the answer - Create the suggestbox myself in the constructor passing in a blank suggestoracle, then manipulate the suggestoracle LATER dynamically:


    public MultiWordSuggestOracle oracleSuggestions = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();
 

    public ucMyControl() {
     txtName = new SuggestBox(oracleSuggestions);
     initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }


then later I could call this code:

    oracleSuggestions.clear();
    for(int i=0; i<Util.arrPeople.length(); i++)
    {
     oracleSuggestions.add(arrPeople.get(i).getName());
    }

Comment: Put the answer in an answer, instead of a comment, please.

Comment: I found that the way which the questioner stated is not enough. 1 more line of code is needed. You can find the whole answer in http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/11/uibinder-with-suggestbox-multiwordsuggestoracle/

Answer (score 10):

Use the method `getSuggestOracle` at `SuggestBox` to get the oracle. By default, it's from type `MultiWordSuggestOracle`. Then, just add the words you want:

```
MultiWordSuggestOracle orcl = (MultiWordSuggestOracle) suggestBox.getSuggestOracle();
orcl.addAll(words);
```

Answer (score 0):

As italo said, get the instance of SuggestOracle with getSuggestOracle(), then you can do a orcl.clear() to clean all the contents and finally addAll().

You can also check out this example that shows a SuggestBox (models) that depends on the selected value  on another main SuggestBox (car brands).

http://siempredesdeelcurro.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/simplest-example-of-gwt-with-eclipse.html